# Unable to log in to my account

Tags: login, lightdm

This is weird,I was reading some blog and I found that I can manually start GUI by issuing this command `sudo startx`,so I did that.Now I'm unable to login to my user account.

Comment: Try restarting your computer.

Comment: Did you that in a terminal window with all GUI already running?

Comment: are you able to login from CLI ?  I mean not from login screen . type ctrl+alt+F1 at the login screen of yours . there are you able to login ?

Comment: If thats not worked , you should try this .http://askubuntu.com/questions/84324/password-reset-disk

Answer (score 1):

OK do the following command from your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

or from CLI with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

If issue not solved then reinstall your lightdm with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

Comment: He can't *log in*, there's no access to the terminal.

Comment: @Oxwivi right but , he has executed sudo startx , i thought he could be there .

Comment: Not if he did from a terminal.

Comment: what ever , he can do my post from terminal or CLI .if its not resolved the issue i gave him a link to reset the password .

Comment: I had to re-install lightdm. :(

Comment: @RajatSaxena How you do that? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @Nur you can do it as ` sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm`

Comment: @Jai Solved my problem, I'm able to login and continue my work, thanks bro :D

Comment: @Nur welcome my friend.